# python data handling with mismatching fields in each line

Tags: python, csv

i am new to python and coding. i have large data like below and want to save it in csv file with fields as the header. All fields are ',' separated and each parameter have value on right side
for example for `LAIGCINAME="LocalLA"` , `LAIGCINAME` is the field and `"LocalLA"` is the value. my problem is all lines have some missing fields. Can anyone help me how to handle this in python as the data us not sync

```
ZXWN:GCI="12345",LAIGCINAME="LocalLA",PROXYLAI=NO,MSCN="11223344",VLRN="11223344",MSAREANAME="0"
ZWGA:GCI="13DADC12",PROXYLAI=NO,MSCVLRTYPE=MSCVLRNUM,MSCN="33223344",VLRN="22334455",MSAREANAME="0",NONBCLAI=NO;
```

Comment: You could try converting the data to a dictionary. The missing keys (i.e. _field_) would just be empty. What are you trying to achieve with this data?

Comment: thanks for your response. i have converted the data to the dictionary, for keys, i want to put it in header and values in the columns of excel file.  how can i update the missing keys

Comment: Just leave them empty and loop over them. Excel can handle CSV files, given they're in the right format. Once you have your list of dictionaries, loop over them and create the lines one by one. Example: https://pastebin.com/rn6TDjMx

Comment: i tried using the list comparison but not getting the desired output. can you please share the script. thanks in advance

Comment: Can the values contain commas or `=` signs?

Comment: yes. it can contain commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data has lots of possible columns names, you will need to first parse the whole file to determine a suitable list of names. Once this is done, the header for the output file can be written followed by all of the data.

By making use of a `csv.DictWriter()` object, missing entries will be written as empty cells. A `restval` parameter could be added if another value is needed for missing values e.g. "N/A"

```
import csv

header = set()
input_filename = 'input.csv'
output_filename = 'output.csv'

with open(input_filename, newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

    # First determine all possible column names
    for row in csv_input:
        header.update({entry.split('=')[0] for entry in row})

with open(input_filename, newline='') as f_input, open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=sorted(header))
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for row in csv_input:
        output_row = {}

        for entry in row:
            key, value = entry.split('=')
            output_row[key] = value.strip('"')

        csv_output.writerow(output_row)
```

For the two lines you have given, this would give you an output file as:

```
LAIGCINAME,MSAREANAME,MSCN,MSCVLRTYPE,NONBCLAI,PROXYLAI,VLRN,ZWGA:GCI,ZXWN:GCI
LocalLA,0,11223344,,,NO,11223344,,12345
,0,33223344,MSCVLRNUM,NO;,NO,22334455,13DADC12,
```

The `csv.dictwriter` works by writing a row from a dictionary, the `csv.writer` works by taking a list of items.

The code creates a single dictionary for each row called `output_row` and then writes it to the output file. By working one row at a time, the script will be able to handle files of any size without running into memory problems.

---

An alternative approach would be to read the whole file into memory and create a list of dictionaries, one for each row. The `header` values could be calculated at the same time. This list of dictionaries could then be written in one go.

For example:

```
import csv

input_filename = 'input.csv'
output_filename = 'output.csv'

header = set()  # Use a set to create unique header values from all rows
output_rows = []    # list of dictionary rows

with open(input_filename, newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        output_row = {}

        for entry in row:
            key, value = entry.split('=')
            output_row[key] = value.strip('"')
            header.add(key)

        output_rows.append(output_row)

with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as f_output:        
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=sorted(header))
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(output_rows)
```

Note, this approach would fail if the file is too big (your question mentions that you have large data).

Comment: Thanks Martin for your great help, As I was trying to do the same using the List of Dictionaries. Can you please help me in this regard as I want to learn the use of multiple dictionaries in the scenario.

Comment: If a list of dictionaries is created i.e. one per row, then your script could run out of memory if your "large data" is too large for your memory.

Comment: it has solved the problem. before I had no understanding of csv module and the above script has helped. thanks again

Comment: Luckily, the data (both input and output -- granted the columns will be the same over split files) is easily split over multiple files. :-)